# Send IP packet from Linux Kernel without destination mac address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ip, ethernet, arp

I want to transmit an skb that contains a valid tcp and ip header in the linux kernel. It should go out a specific interface without being routed.
My problem is, that I cannot use `dev_queue_xmit` because I dont know the destination mac-address. 
My attempts to find out the mac-address with `arp_find` failed:

```
...
mh = (struct ethhdr *) skb_push(skb, sizeof(struct ethhdr));
...
arp_find(mh->h_dest, skb); //this or the next line
val = dev_queue_xmit(skb); //crashes kernel
```

Experiments with `ip_local_out` also failed. I set the ip header information and call `ip_local_out` which also results in a kernel crash.

I could not use `ip_queue_xmit` because I was not able to find out, what data to provide in the `struct flowi *fl` field.

So my questions:

- How can I send out an skb on a device with ip information and no knowledge about lower levels?
- If there is no answer to the first question: How can I find out the destination mac/trigger an arp request for the destination ip?

Remark:

- I would like to avoid using (raw) sockets.
- I have successfully
  transmitted self-made skbs via `dev_queue_xmit` if I had the
  destination mac address. So the code building the skb is not an
  issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you still want to use `ip_local_out` or `ip_queue_xmit`, then you can create your flowinfo like this.

```
struct flowi4 fl4 = {
    .flowi4_oif = skb->dev->ifindex,
    .daddr = iph->daddr,
    .saddr = iph->saddr,
};
```

then create dst(rtable) with

```
ip_route_output_key
```

set to skb_buff with

```
skb_dst_set
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a cleaner solution to use socket programming in kernel to send it as RAW IP packet.
You can create socket like this. 

`sock_create_kern(&sk, AF_INET,
                         SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW,
                         net);`

then call 

`kernel_sendmsg`

to let your packet going through the protocol stack.